# Global Models in SailsJS not accessible

Tags: sails.js

In porting a sails app to 1.x framework.  I found that my global model names (which are physically defined in api/models directory) were undefined in one of my hook initialize function and in config/bootstrap.js

"models": true, is defined in config/globals.js in this project.

For example, one of my models is Job.js:

```
const async = require('async');
const _ = require('lodash');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: 'integer',
            autoIncrement: false,
            unique: true,
            primaryKey: true
        }
    },
    Init: function(params,cb) {
        sails.log.info('Job Engine Starting');
        ...
    }
}
```

But, when I try to call Job.Init(), from hooks/index.js or from config/bootstrap.js, I get reference error: Job is undefined.

Comment: If you are looking for job queue, I'd suggest to use this hook : 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@logisticinfotech/sails-hook-job-queue

Comment: I tried with minimum example, and it seems working fine to me, would you like to give more description for your problem?